# Rspec test got: nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

I'm trying to do a basic rspec test, which looks like this;

```
require 'rails_helper'

  describe ReviewsController do

  describe "GET #index" do
   it "assigns a new review to @reviews" do
   review = Review.create( rating: 4 )

   get :index

   expect(assigns(:review)).to eq([review])
   assert_response :success
  end
 end
end
```

But I'm getting the failure: expected: Review id: 8, rating: 4, created_at: "2016-07-19 11:58:28", updated_at: "2016-07-19 11:58:28", user_id: nil, game_id: nil
            got: nil

My ReviewsController looks like this:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

  def index
   @reviews = Review.all
  end

  def show
   @review = Review.find(params[:rating])
  end

  def create
   review = Review.new(review_params)

   respond_to do |format|
   if @review.save
    format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Review was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @review }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
 end

  private

  def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:message)
  end
 end
```

In case you need it, here's the review model:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :game
 validates_presence_of :rating

 validates_uniqueness_of :user_id
end
```

I don't understand why it's asking for a user_id or game_id, because it's only about the reviews..

Comment: You're getting that error message because of the association in your models. Review belongs to Game and User and therefore on creation of Review there needs to be an assigned game and user id.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the below

```
expect(assigns(:review)).to eq([review])
```

to

```
expect(assigns(:reviews)).to eq([review])
```

The reason is `@reviews` is the instance variable you have inside the `#index` controller action, not `@review`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still getting the exact same error though, but at least that's one mistake less.

Comment: Failures:

  1) ReviewsController GET #index assigns a new review to @reviews
     Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:reviews)).to eq([review])
     
       expected: [#<Review id: 10, rating: 4, created_at: "2016-07-19 12:29:57", updated_at: "2016-07-19 12:29:57", user_id: nil, game_id: nil>]
            got: nil

Comment: try `Review.create!( rating: 4 )` and tell what you see

Comment: Tried it, but nothing changed, still the same failure.

Comment: except that failure there is no more error, you sure?

Comment: you shouldn't have the error if you change the code as I suggested. Are you sure you saved the code?

Comment: Yes I saved it, double checked. I'm thinking there might be something wrong with the model??
This is the failure I'm getting:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/uMjOR.jpg

Comment: I don't think it is a model issue because `#create!` don't raise any error

Comment: Can you check whether the review you create in your test is saved in your test database ?

Comment: @Jakeroo you should create your associative data(user and game) as well when testing, in this case it can be ignored but its a good practice.

Comment: @Jakeroo add a user id since you have a uniqueness check at the model level so it creates a review as per the rules you have defined. And then run the test. You can do something similar for the gameId as well.

Comment: You were right, there's nothing wrong with the model/test, something's wrong with my Devise setup. The server response is 302 instead of 200...

Comment: @Jakeroo open a terminal and run `tail -f log/test.log` and then run the test and watch in the log to see where the request is going. One way to debug the issue

Comment: @ArupRakshit nice! It stopped at Processing by ReviewsController#index as HTML Completed 401 Unauthorized. And when I changed the test to     expect(response.status).to eq(200) it also gave me the failure expected: 200, got: 302.

Devise is definitely the problem.

Comment: yeah so you got it :) You have to authenticate before access the controller. work on it.

Comment: Another stupid question, but is that as simple as adding before_action :authenticate_user! at the top of the controller? Because it's not working...